# Finding a non-zero continuous function on $[1,2]$ orthogonal to the set $\{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\frac{n \pi}{\ln 2}\ln x),~x \in[1,2],~n=\pm1,...,\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a set of functions $\{f_n:[1,2] \to \mathbb R,~n=\pm1,\pm2,...\}$ defined by $$f_n(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\frac{n \pi}{\ln 2}\ln x),~x \in[1,2],~n=\pm1,\pm2,...,$$
I tried for a non trivial continuous function $g:[1,\ 2]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{1}^{2}g(x)f_n(x)dx=0$ for all $n=\pm1,\pm2,...$, But I couldn't find such a function. Is it possible?

OR

Can we prove there is some $f_n$ such that $\int_{1}^{2}g(x)f_n(x)dx \neq 0$ for any non-zero continuous function $g:[1,\ 2]\to\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function. I presume that we can use that $\{\sin(nx): n=1,2,\ldots\}$ form an orthogonal basis for $L^2([0,\pi])$ (square integrable functions on $[0,\pi]$). Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[1,2]$. Then it belongs to $L^2([1,2])$ as well. Let $k$ be a natural number. By substituting $\frac{\pi\ln x}{\ln 2} = t$ we get
\begin{align*}
\int_1^2 f(x) x^{-1/2}\sin \big(\frac {k\pi}{\ln 2}\ln x\big)\, dx = \frac {\ln 2}\pi\int_0^\pi f(2^{t/\pi}) 2^{t/2\pi} \sin(kt)\, dt.
\end{align*}
The function $t\mapsto f(2^{t/\pi}) 2^{t/2\pi}$ is continuous and non-trivial on $[0,\pi]$, so the last integral cannot be equal to zero for all $k$, because that would contradict the fact that $\{\sin(nx): n=1,2,\ldots\}$ form a basis for $L^2([0,\pi])$.

Comment: You're right, thanks!